# Implementaion of DooD (Docker outside of Docker) in GoCD-Agent

Tags: docker, go-cd

There is a way of setting up a DooD scenario in GoCD as it's clearly written in their official site:  [Here is The Documentaion](https://docs.gocd.org/current/gocd_on_kubernetes/docker_workflows.html)

And though it's suggesting to add a volume to connect the host docker socket with the GoCD agent container, no docker command is executing from the running agent.

docker-compose.yml:

```
agent:
image: gocd/gocd-agent-docker-dind:v19.12.0
volumes:
  - ./ssh-location:/home/go/.ssh
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
environment:
  - GO_SERVER_URL="https://server:8154/go"
links:
  - server
depends_on:
  - server
```

Is there a clear way of setting up a GoCD agent image to send a docker command to the host machine?

Answer (score 1):

Hooray, it was a bug and has already been fixed. (i.e. [Github Issue](https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/7557))